# Found a way to convert drive from GPT to MBR and vice versa without data loss but,

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I also have found a way to convert drive from GPT to MBR and vice versa without data loss using the AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro Edition 6.0 but, I fear because actually, I have Windows 10 already installed on a GPT drive and I'm interested in installing Windows 7, but for that my drive should be MBR (although it should work on GPT but it's not)

**So, if I convert my drive from GPT to MBR without data loss using the AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro Edition 6.0 will it effect my current windows 10 which is already installed on a GPT drive i.e will it stop functioning get corrupt etc?** I want to keep both Windows 10 and Windows 7.

Please share your advice!

> EDIT:

Here is the PIC of my UEFI. Compatibility Support Module (CSM) is enabled.

[image]

> EDIT:

After I create a USB Bootable drive of Windows 7 x64 (download from Microsoft Dreamspark) and created by RUFUS with GPT and UEFI compatible **(CSM DISABLED)**, it gives me this error. If I press the Enter button it boots normally into Windows 10. I think I am very near to solve the problem. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Windows 7 x64 supports GPT and specifically UEFI mode.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I could not install Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on ASUS G551JW laptop. It gives me an error whenever I install it using the Launch PXE Op ROM enabled at selecting the drive to install **"The selected partition is of GPT"**. I even tried to alter the settings in bios, but it didn't work. Should I post my Bios pics?

Comment: If you have CSM enabled it means your not booting in UEFI mode.  CSM and GPT cannot co-exist if your using Windows.  **If you can't figure this out don't do the conversion**

Comment: @Ramhound bro, I have updated the question. Please help me. I think I'm near to solve the problem now.

Comment: try booting off the install CD, then getting a command prompt.  Then type:  **bootrec /rebuildbcd**, and says yes to add whatever it finds.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the hard drive from GPT to MBR Windows 10 won't boot anymore.

Since your receiving the error  "The selected partition is of GPT" then you must of booted the Windows 7 installer using MBR by accident. Most BIOS' will let you push a button to select the boot device at startup (e.g. F12). Make sure you select the EFI DVD or USB option. How exactly it looks will depend on your system's BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I have uploaded the pic of my UEFI. I even selected the CSM options to provide backward compatibility, but it doesn't work and give that error. I can sure go to the setup of Windows 7, but can't select the partition because of that error of "The selected Partition is of GPT only"

Comment: You want "Launch CSM" set to Disabled. Since you have it on, it's booting the Windows installer in MBR/legacy mode.

Comment: I also did it that way, but then it didn't even boot in GPT mode. I used the Rufus software to make a GPT compatible USB drive from ISO of Windows 7 x64, but it didn't work. Please help me. I love Windows 7

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"? Was there an error message? Or did it just not boot? Try selecting the last option in rufus under Partition scheme "GPT partition screen for UEFI".

Comment: I did that only. It gives an error "bootx64.efi" not found. I somehow even managed to copy that file, but then it gave a black screen of Windows 7 setup

Comment: The only other options I can think of are to try a different Windows iso file (maybe it's corrupted) or to reinstall Windows 10 using MBR first. You could give the AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro a try if you have everything backed up and are going to reinstall otherwise.

Comment: If it cannot find the EFI driver then the bootable media was created incorrectly

Comment: @Curtis bro, I have updated the question. Please help me. I think I'm near to solve the problem now.

Comment: You could try disabling "secure boot" and "fast boot". Also make sure you are plugging into a USB 2 port or enable legacy USB support if all the ports are USB 3. Windows 7 doesn't support USB 3 until after you install drivers.